# Extract PDF Annotations in Automator isn't getting the content

Tags: macos, automator, pdf, preview

OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. I'm using Preview.app to annotate PDFs. Now I want to extract all of the annotations from the documents, so I open Automator.app and connect the "Get Specified Finder Items" and "Extract PDF Annotations" together.

I ran it, and I get all of the metadata of annotations, but not any of the content.

[image]

Comment: I get the same behavior for El Capitan.